# Identicality, equality and linearity of i.i.d random variables. What are some examples if iid r.vs are unequal among themselves?

Tags: probability, problem-solving, independence, covariance

I need to understand some underlying concepts and facts regarding [i.i.d](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_and_identically_distributed_random_variables) random variables.

> The problem is $$\textrm{Suppose } \mathrm{X_1, X_2, X_3 } \textrm{ are i.i.d positive valued r.v.s.}\\ \textrm{Define } \mathrm{Y_i=\frac{X_i}{X_1+X_2+X_3} \textrm{, i=1,2,3. Find the correlation between } Y_1 \textrm{ and } Y_3.}$$

Here is the first approach to solve, $$\mathrm{\sum_{i=1}^{3} Y_i=1 \textrm{ and since X_i's are iid, hence each of } Y_i=\frac{1}{3}. Therefore, \mathbb{E}(Y_i)=\frac{1}{3} \textrm{ for i=1,2,3.}}\\ \mathrm{\textrm{To find } \mathbb{E}(Y_{1}^{2}) \textrm{ and } \mathbb{E}(Y_{3}^{2}) \textrm{ we have }}\\ \mathrm{1=\mathbb{E}\bigg[\frac{(X_1+X_2+X_3)^2}{(X_1+X_2+X_3)^2}\bigg]}\\=\mathrm{\mathbb{E} \bigg[\frac{3X_{1}^{2}}{(X_1+X_2+X_3)^2}+\frac{2(X_1X_2+X_2X_3+X_3X_1)}{(X_1+X_2+X_3)^2}\bigg]}\\=\mathrm{\mathbb{E} \bigg[3Y_{1}^{2}+2(Y_1Y_2+Y_2Y_3+Y_3Y_1)\bigg]}\\=\mathrm{\mathbb{E} \bigg[3Y_{1}^{2}+2[Y_1(1-Y_1)+Y_2Y_3]\bigg]}\\=\mathrm{\mathbb{E} \bigg[Y_{1}^{2}+2Y_1+Y_2Y_3\bigg]}\\=\mathrm{\mathbb{E} \bigg[Y_{1}^{2}+2Y_1+Y_2Y_3\bigg]}\\=\mathrm{\mathbb{E} \bigg[Y_{1}^{2}-\frac{2Y_1}{3}+\frac{1}{9}+\frac{8}{9}+\frac{8Y_1}{3}+Y_2Y_3-1\bigg]}\\=\mathrm{\mathbb{V}(Y_1)+\mathbb{E} \bigg[\frac{8}{9}+\frac{8Y_1}{3}+Y_2Y_3-1\bigg]}\\=\mathrm{0+\mathbb{E}[\frac{7}{9}+Y_2Y_3]}\\\Longrightarrow \mathrm{\mathbb{E}[Y_2Y_3]=\frac{2}{9}}\\\Longrightarrow \mathrm{\mathbb{E}[Y_2Y_3]=\mathbb{E}[Y_2+Y_3]}$$

Hence I need to know that

-What can we conclude from this solution?

My second approach is as follows :

$$\mathrm{\textrm{If Y_i's are not independent then they are indentical only, } cov(Y_1, Y_1+Y_2+Y_3)=cov(Y_1, 1)=0}\\\Longrightarrow \mathrm{\mathbb{V}(Y_1)+cov(Y_1,Y_2)+cov(Y_1,Y_3)=0}\\ \mathrm{\textrm{Now due to identicality if the covariance  } (Y_1,Y_2) = \textrm{  covariance  } (Y_1,Y_3) \textrm{ and , }\mathbb{V}(Y_1)=\mathbb{V}(Y_3) \textrm{, then my problem is solved.}}$$

- From here if $Y_i$'s are identical then their variances are similar to each other and covariance are similar to each other. Hence the r.vs $Y_i$ are equal due to identicality. is it a correct statement?

Any help or explanation is valuable and highly appreciated.

---

Here is a post from this website where the given hint says that the [iid rv.s are equal according to distrbution but unequal among themselves](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2820317/equality-of-expecations-regarding-i-i-d-random-variables). Is there any example available?

Comment: As $Y_1+Y_2+Y_3=1$, the $Y_i$ are surely not independent.

Comment: @AnginaSeng, just to know, if there were $0$ instead of $1$ or if we could express any one of $Y_i$s in term of others .. would it be then independent?

Comment: They would definitely not be.

Comment: And unless the $X_i$ are equal, the $Y_i$ are not all equal.  Try an example, e.g. $X_i = 1$ with probability $p$ and $2$ with probability $1-p$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:
By symmetry, $\text{Cov}(Y_1, Y_3) = \text{Cov}(Y_1, Y_2)$ so
$$\eqalign{\text{Cov}(Y_1,Y_3) &= \frac{1}{2} \text{Cov}(Y_1,Y_2+Y_3)\cr
                               &= \frac{1}{2} \text{Cov}(Y_1, 1-Y_1)\cr}$$
Express this in terms of $\text{Var}(Y_1)$...

Comment: We have the informations that $Y_i$ are identical and $Y_1+Y_2+Y_3=1$. Is it the   property called 'identical' for which we can use symmetry on covariance?

Comment: No, they are not identical (except in the trivial case where the $X_i$ are almost surely constant).  The symmetry is interchange of $X_2$ and $X_3$.